# Cuadrar un div vertical y horizontalmente con el footer pegado abajo de la página sin que salga un espacio en blanco debajo del footer

Tags: html5, css3

Quiero cuadrar el div horizontalmente y verticalmente y el problema viene cuando: si no pongo el footer en position: fixed para que se quede abajo del todo, se me queda un espacio blanco abajo del footer
(entiendo que es porque no ocupa el mínimo espacio del height) y si pongo el footer position:fixed, el footer se queda bien, pero no hay manera de que el div(class="formularioGeneral, el div que pone formulario enviado) se posicione verticalmente y horizontalmente en la pantalla según el diametro de la pantalla. Tendría que ir jugando con margenes dependiendo de cada tamaño pero creo que habrá alguna forma mas fácil que no consigo sacar.
Muchas gracias y buen finde semana a tod@s.

HTML5

```
   <div class="opacidadMEnu">

        <!-- <h3 class="separador">FORMULARIO</h3> -->


        <div class="formularioGeneral">

            <div class="formularioOK">

                <div class="formularioOK__div">

                    <div>
                        <p class="formularioOK__div-p ">Formulario enviado</p>
                        <div>
                            <img class="formularioOK__div-p-img " src="./img/pulgar-arriba.png" alt="pulgar arriba">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>



            </div>
            <!-- div formularioOK -->


        </div>


        <footer class="footer_abajoSticky">


            <div class="footer_fondo">
                <div class=" footer_abajo__primero ">
                    <nav class="iconos_footer contenedor">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </nav>
                    <nav class="footer_abajo__segundo">
                        <a href="">inicio</a>
                        <a href="">quien soy</a>
                        <a href="">servicios</a>
                    </nav>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="fondo_footer">
                <div class="footer_final contenedor">
                    <p>todos los derechos reservados &copy;</p>
                    <p><span class="footer__final-p-span">dj chete</span></p>
                </div>

            </div>


        </footer>


    </div> 
    <!-- div opacidad menu -->
```

CSS3

```
.formularioGeneral{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 585px;
}
.formularioOK__div{
    background-color: rgb(245, 209, 199);
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    padding: 20px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border: 5px dashed #f8704a;
    
    
}
.formularioOK__div-p {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: calc(3vw + 3vh);
    margin: 0;
}
.formularioOK__div-p-img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 25%;
   max-height: 25%;
  

}
.footer_abajoSticky{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
     
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que investigues acerca de los Media Query en CSS, te serán muy útiles para que una web sea Mobile Friendly

Answer (score 0):

En este caso si lo que necesitas es que el footer siempre esté en el final de la página lo que puedes hacer es jugar con la propiedad **position** de **css**. En el código que has compartido bastaría con cambiar del siguiente modo el **position** a **relative**, apoyando este cambio con una coordenada exacta al final de la página donde quieres que permanezca el **footer** con el **bottom**, como ya habías hecho:

```css
.formularioGeneral{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /*height: 585px;*/
    height: auto;
}
.formularioOK__div{
    background-color: rgb(245, 209, 199);
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    padding: 20px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    border: 5px dashed #f8704a;
}
.formularioOK__div-p {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: calc(3vw + 3vh);
    margin: 0;
}
.formularioOK__div-p-img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 25%;
   max-height: 25%;
}
.footer_abajoSticky{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    background-color: red;
    }
.footer_abajoSticky .footer_fondo{
    display: flex;    
    justify-content: center;
}
.footer_abajoSticky .fondo_footer{
    display: flex;    
    justify-content: center;
}
.footer_abajoSticky nav a {flex-direction: row;}
```

```html
<div class="opacidadMEnu">
        <div class="formularioGeneral">
            <div class="formularioOK">
                <div class="formularioOK__div">
                    <div>
                        <p class="formularioOK__div-p ">Formulario enviado</p>
                        <div>
                            <img class="formularioOK__div-p-img " src="./img/pulgar-arriba.png" alt="pulgar arriba">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer_abajoSticky">
            <div class="footer_fondo">
                <div class=" footer_abajo__primero ">
                    <nav class="iconos_footer contenedor">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </nav>
                    <nav class="footer_abajo__segundo">
                        <a href="">inicio</a>
                        <a href="">quien soy</a>
                        <a href="">servicios</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fondo_footer">
                <div class="footer_final contenedor">
                    <p>todos los derechos reservados &copy;</p>
                    <p><span class="footer__final-p-span">dj chete</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Además, para centrar los elementos del **footer** dentro de su contenedor he utilizado la propiedad **display:flex** para que de este modo, otorgándole la posición **justify-items:center**, dicho elementos siempre se posicionen del modo que muestras en las imágenes que compartes arriba.

A continuación comparto un enlace a la documentación sobre el uso **[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)** que quizán pueda resultar de ayuda y otro sobre el uso de las propiedades **[position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)**.